# Nvidia-smi missing GPU with SR-IOV disable in bios

Tags: linux, virtualization, nvidia, gpu, sr-iov

I have a HPE serveur (DL385) with 3 Nvidia A100 in it. It is running ubuntu 22.04 with kernel version 6 (I have tried with the 5).
By default, it was in energy saving mode in the BIOS.

When I tried to put it in HPC mode, a mode that disable some feature like SR-IOV and change the numa configuration among other things, the command nvidia-smi show just one GPU.

But with lspci | grep NVIDIA I still see all of them

To find back the GPUs in nvidia-smi, I have to enable SR-IOV back (just SR-IOV is enought).

I don't have this kind a problem with a similar server running fedora 36.

Someone knows what is happening here?

Thanks,

Guillaume